# Writing functions of tuples conveniently in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

Quite a few functions on `Map` take a function on a key-value tuple as the argument. E.g. `def foreach(f: ((A, B)) ⇒ Unit): Unit`. So I looked for a short way to write an argument to `foreach`:

```
> val map = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4)

map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4)

> map.foreach((k, v) => println(k))

error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1
       map.foreach((k, v) => println(k))
                          ^

> map.foreach({(k, v) => println(k)})

error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1
       map.foreach({(k, v) => println(k)})
                           ^

> map.foreach(case (k, v) => println(k))

error: illegal start of simple expression
       map.foreach(case (k, v) => println(k))
                   ^
```

I can do

```
> map.foreach(_ match {case (k, v) => println(k)})

1
3
```

Any better alternatives?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You were very close with `map.foreach(case (k, v) => println(k))`. To use `case` in an anonymous function, surround it by curly brackets.

```
map foreach { case (k, v) => println(k) }
```

Answer (score 13):

In such cases I often use the `for` syntax.

```
for ((k,v) <- map) println(k)
```

According to Chapter 23 in "Programming in Scala" the above for loop is translated to call `foreach`.

Comment: Just a note: one should use a separate `flatten` if he would want a `flatMap` with this approach.

Comment: A lot of times it is more functional to use `foreach`.  If you find yourself doing it this way there is probably some abstraction that can be done.

Answer (score 5):

One alternative is the `tupled` method of the `Function` object:

```
import Function.tupled;
// map tupled foreach {(k, v) => println(k)}
map foreach tupled {(k, v) => println(k)}
```

Comment: @Rahul `map foreach Function.tupled((k,v) => println(k))` or `map foreach ((k : Int,v : Int) => println(k)).tupled` does.

Comment: Yes, sorry I accidently swapped `tupled` and the function call. I'll change it.

Comment: A clever solution. I was unaware of this, and now I learned something. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason one would use this over the accepted answer (Ben Lings)?

Answer (score 3):

You can also access a tuple as follows:

```
scala> val map = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4)
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map((1,2), (3,4))
scala> map foreach (t => println(t._1))
1
3
```

Comment: Yes, forgot to add that alternative. But I don't like it, because in this case the fields of tuple do have actual meaning (key and value) and I want to reflect it in my code.

Answer (score 2):

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.Beta1-prerelease (OpenJDK Server VM, Java 1.6.0_0).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val m = Map('a -> 'b, 'c -> 'd)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Symbol,Symbol] = Map('a -> 'b, 'c -> 'd)

scala> m foreach { case(k, v) => println(k) }
'a
'c
```

Answer (score 1):

I was pretty close with the last attempt, actually:

```
> map.foreach({case (k, v) => println(k)})
1
3
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the most outer round braces(). Just `foreach{case (k,v)=> ???}`