# MapValues with the tuple as Value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an `RDD, say r1 = Array((a,(1,5)), (b,(2,3)) )`. I want to apply mapValues on this RDD. I am stuck on how to apply a function which will change each value in the tuple or pair by 1. I tried :

```
r1.mapValues((x,y) => (x+1,y+1))
```

but it is throwing the following error:

```
error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1 val r4 = r1.mapValues((x,y) => (x+1, y+1) )
```

Comment: error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1
       val r4 = r1.mapValues((x,y) => (x+1, y+1) )

Comment: You cannot use map with tuples like that. Try `r1.mapValues { case (x,y) => (x+1,y+1) }`

Comment: Thanks @SaschaKolberg it worked

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing functions of tuples conveniently in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957254/writing-functions-of-tuples-conveniently-in-scala)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mapValues allows you to map the existing value to a new value, for each key. 
So semantics for this method allow you to map exactly one value to another.

Try below code instead

```
r1.mapValues(x => (x._1+1,x._2+1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `match/case` like `r1.mapValues { case (a,b) => (a+1,b+1) }` as show in below.

Example:

```
scala> val a = Array(('a', (1,5)), ('b',(2,3)) )
a: Array[(Char, (Int, Int))] = Array((a,(1,5)), (b,(2,3)))

scala> val r1 = sc.parallelize(a)

scala> r1.collect()

res0: Array[(Char, (Int, Int))] = Array((a,(1,5)), (b,(2,3)))

scala> val r2 = r1.mapValues { case (a,b) => (a+1,b+1) }
scala> r2.collect()

res1: Array[(Char, (Int, Int))] = Array((a,(2,6)), (b,(3,4)))
```